# Can't I use LINQ in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I use LinQ in LinQ. Then there is an Error.

> "You can't change type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`' to '`string`'."

Here is my code.

```
var reList = (from temp in list
                    select new ListData
                    {
                        Id = temp._Id,
                        Nm = temp._Nm,
                        Type = (from ex in Types
                                where ex.ID == temp._type
                                select ex.Cd_Nm)
                    }).ToList();
return reList;
```

There is only one value in

```
(from ex in Types
     where ex.ID == temp._type
     select ex.Cd_Nm)
```

ToString() is working, but not show string value, just show Type name.

How can I use? How can I fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the

```
select ex.Cd_Nm)
```

add

`.First()` or `.Single()` (or `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.SingleOrDefault()` if it can be optional)...

You want a *single* (or perhaps 0-1, it isn't clear) value from that `select`, not an `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: Why didn't I know that? Thanks a lot ! It works well ! :)